# CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When compiling a project, Unity 5.6.3p2 produces the following error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
C:\Users\Robot\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.0\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "C:/Users/Robot/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.chartboost.sdk.unity:com.unity.purchasing:com.sglib.mobile.androidnative:com.android.vending.billing:com.google.unity.ads:com.unity.purchasing.googleplay:com.google.example.games.mainlibproj:com.google.games.bridge:com.google.android.gms.ads.impl:com.google.android.gms.admob.impl.license:com.google.android.gms.ads:com.google.android.gms.admob.license:com.google.android.gms.auth.api:com.google.android.gms.auth:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.common.license:com.google.android.gms.drive:com.google.android.gms.games:com.google.android.gms.gass:com.google.android.gms.gass.license:com.google.android.gms.nearby:com.google.android.gms.tasks:android.support.compat:android.support.coreui:android.support.coreutils:android.support.fragment:android.support.mediacompat:android.support.v4 -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\common\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\mobile\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GoogleAIDL\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GooglePlay\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gpgs-plugin-support-0.9.42\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-11.6.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-lite-11.6.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-auth-11.6.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-auth-base-11.6.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-11.6.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-11.6.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-9.0.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-drive-11.6.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-games-11.6.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-gass-11.6.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-nearby-11.6.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-tasks-11.6.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-compat-25.2.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-core-ui-25.2.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-core-utils-25.2.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-fragment-25.2.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-media-compat-25.2.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-25.2.0\res"

stderr[
C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\mobile\res\layout\ratingdialog.xml:7: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <TextView>
C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\mobile\res\layout\ratingdialog.xml:7: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <TextView>
C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\mobile\res\layout\ratingdialog.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.Robot.S:layout/ratingdialog for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-11.6.0\res\values\values.xml:33: error: Attribute "imageAspectRatioAdjust" already defined with incompatible format.
C:\Users\Robot\Desktop\UnityProjects\S(Test)\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-9.0.0\res\values\values.xml:3: Original attribute defined here.
]
```

I tried to make many tips specified in similar topics, but it seems that I have a conflict between the plugins in the project, so I would like to know from the professionals in this conflict is to blame or I just use the wrong version of the tools

Comment: `"imageAspectRatioAdjust" already defined with incompatible format.` One of your plugins seems to be setting imageAspectRatioAdjust to a format that is incompatible with Android devices. Do you have any plugins that would effect that property?

Comment: Such a mistake appeared after I started using Chartboost in the project in conjunction with Google Admob.

Comment: There's really no reason to ever use more than one Ad network. They are probably both fighting to set the AspectRatioAdjust for their own respective ads. Just use one AD network. If you need more ads then create them in AdMob or whichever one you choose to go with and add them where you want...